# Unable to read response data using HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
byte[] content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(content,0,content.Length);
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 

reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
String resultData = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I am getting data in response, also on doing Quick Watch of reader.ReadToEnd() it shows data in VS, but resultData always comes empty.

Any Idea what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Any reason you're not using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)?

Comment: You should be making use of the `using` statement whenever you are dealing with objects which implement `IDisposable` i.e. `StreamReader`/`WebResponse`. Have a read of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `reader.ReadToEnd()` in the debugger, then by the time you try to call `ReadToEnd()` within the actual code, there won't be any more data.

Note that you should use a `using` statement for the response, so that you close it when you're done.

Answer (score -2):

Your code has multiple problems (`ContentLength` should be `content.Length` not `data.Length`; disposable resources should be disposed), but I'm not sure which one is responsible for the behaviour you see.

However, your code can be slightly shortened when you use the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

    string resultData = client.UploadString(url, data);
}
```

Maybe you can check if this works in your case.